# Delete a line drawn by abline()

Tags: r

How to delete a line drawn by function abline without changing the color to match background? 
Btw, I am using chart_Series for charting. It would be great to have xy lines (1 vertical and 1 horizontal) following the mouse movement. 
Pls help

Comment: Once drawn, removing is not possible. You need to redraw the whole image.

Answer (score 10):

You can't, R uses a "pen on paper" model for it's base graphics. Once you taint the "paper" (device) with any plotting object it is there for good. You need to redo the entire plot without the line in order to "remove" it. Painting over the line with the same data in the background colour just fakes deletion; as far as R is concerned you now have two lines, one on top of another.

Comment: This is not as bad as it sounds.  Once you get used to redrawing plots rather than hand-tinkering with them a' la Excel, it's really faster and simpler.  Just put all the plotting commands into a script or function (or learn ggplot :-) ) and edit/redraw is a snap.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the question is that you want an interactive plot.

There are number of packages that allow interactive plots.

The one you can use with plot functions from other packages and from base is

```
library(playwith)
playwith(chart_Series(...))
```

Note this requires Gtk+ installed on you computer.

You may also want to create your own widget using

```
rpanel
```

Most interactive plotting use their own plotting functions and may not be compatible with chart_Series.

```
iplot
rggobi
```

You may also find base R functions useful

```
identify(x, y, labels=row.names(mydata))
coords <- locator(type="l")
coords
```